# chrome extension storage api syntax

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'overlayColor': color});                        

var get = chrome.storage.sync.get('overlayColor',function());
```

Why do I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" for the 2nd line??

By the way, if I take away the call back function in get function, the error becomes:

extensions::StorageArea:35 Uncaught Error: Invocation of form get(string) doesn't match definition get(optional string or array or object keys, function callback)
    at normalizeArgumentsAndValidate (extensions::schemaUtils:115:11)
    at StorageArea.self.(anonymous function) [as get] (extensions::StorageArea:35:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.changeOverlayColor (chrome-extension://neihdeocppgagfakakclajlmbgognbbc/option.js:9:35)
    at Object.fireEvent (chrome-extension://neihdeocppgagfakakclajlmbgognbbc/jscolor.js:240:7)
    at Object.dispatchChange (chrome-extension://neihdeocppgagfakakclajlmbgognbbc/jscolor.js:675:9)
    at HTMLDocument. (chrome-extension://neihdeocppgagfakakclajlmbgognbbc/jscolor.js:667:8)

Answer (score 0):

The function is missing the curly braces. You will need to replace `function()` with `function() {}`

```
var get = chrome.storage.sync.get('overlayColor',function() {});
```

The function doesn't return the data so instead of storing the result in a variable, you will want to put the logic needing the values in the callback

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('overlayColor',function(data) {
  // use data here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Function is not properly declared. Correct syntax is as following:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('overlayColor', function (result) {
    var get = result.overlayColor;
});
```